# Maximum size of Stream/Bitmap in WallpaperManager

Tags: android

I'm trying to set a resource/stream as Wallpaper in Android. I use the WallpaperManager class and its methods setResource/setStream to do this. I normally scale the images using BitmapFactory.Options before I set them as wallpaper. But this time I wanted to try the full image without any scaling. So I tried to set an image with a resoultion of 5005 x 3274 as wallpaper, without any scaling. And to my surprise, the avd's wallpaper changed to the default stock wallpaper. No exception and no error logs. Below is the code I use.

So is there any limit for the size of wallpaper that can be set? I cannot find any information about maximum image size in WallpaperManager docs. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public void onBtnClick(View view) {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run(){
            try{
               mgr.setResource(R.drawable.wallpaper);
               mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                   public void run(){
                       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.toast_success, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
               });
            } catch(Exception ioe) { 
                  Log.w("WallpaperManager", ioe.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's too late... anyway, it should be within 4096 x 4096(Tested under API 17, SDK 4.2), or the home application will be crash and the default wallpaper will be set.